# in R how to count the number of times a value appears and meet multiple criteria

Tags: r

example:

```
Colour   vehicle      city         type
red       car         London       Petrol
blue      truck       Paris        Diesel
red       car         NewYork      Electric
green     van         Barcelona    Petrol
black     motorbike   LosAngeles   Petrol
```

i.e. How to count number of times that "car" appears and it's "red" and "Petrol"

this is what I tried

```
sum(full_data$vehicle == "car" & full_data$Colour == "red" & 
  full_data$type == "Petrol")
```

Comment: Please show the code of your best attempt.

Comment: Your code looks fine.  I get `sum(full_data$vehicle == "car" & full_data$Colour == "red" & 
   full_data$type == "Petrol")#
[1] 1`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I just edited it. Thanks !

Comment: If the code is returning the "1" you need, where is the question here?

Comment: it was returning NA, I just sorted it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `full_data` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end your code works for me.

```
# 1
sum(full_data$vehicle == "car" & full_data$Colour == "red" & 
   full_data$type == "Petrol")
## [1] 1
```

If the question is how to improve the code then try `with`.  Also if there are NAs in the data (there are none in the question) we can handle it by using `which(...)` around the logical expression and then using `length` instead of `sum`.

```
# 2
with(full_data, length(which(vehicle == "car" & Colour == "red" & type == "Petrol")))
## [1] 1
```

Any of these would also work:

```
# 3
nrow(subset(full_data, vehicle == "car" & Colour == "red" & type == "Petrol"))
## [1] 1

library(dplyr)
full_data %>% 
  filter(vehicle == "car" & Colour == "red" & type == "Petrol") %>%
  nrow
## [1] 1

# 4
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select count(*) as count from full_data 
  where vehicle == "car" and Colour == "red" and type == "Petrol"')
##   count
## 1     1
```

### Note

```
full_data <- structure(list(Colour = c("red", "blue", "red", "green", "black"
), vehicle = c("car", "truck", "car", "van", "motorbike"), city = c("London", 
"Paris", "NewYork", "Barcelona", "LosAngeles"), type = c("Petrol", 
"Diesel", "Electric", "Petrol", "Petrol")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your third option worked ! I don't know why it was returning NA with my code

Comment: There were no NAs in the question but I have modified the solutions (except #1) to address that.